# Couldn't show my simple bar charts separately on Shiny R dashboardBody

Tags: r, shiny, bar-chart, shinydashboard, shinyapps

So I'm trying to make a very simple Shiny R dashboard that shows the progress percentage which will be linked to an editable excel file. here's an example data:

```
| Month    | PERCENTAGE     |
|:---------|:---------------|
| JAN      | 90             |
| FEB      | 78             |
| MAR      | 100            |
| APR      | 99             |
| MAY      | 90             |
| JUN      | 78             |
| JUL      | 100            |
| AUG      | 87             |
| SEP      | 90             |
| OCT      | 78             |
| NOV      | 99             |
| DES      | 100            |
```

Here's my ui.R code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
library(shinyalert)

# data1 <- read_excel ("Data1.xlsx")

shinydashboard::dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
              dashboardHeader(title = "UPDL PANDAAN"),
              
              #sidebar
              dashboardSidebar(
                sidebarMenu(
                  menuItem("WIG PMK 2020", tabName = "WIGPMK", icon = icon("tachometer-alt")),
                  fluidPage(
                    actionButton("myButton", "About Us")
                  )
                )),
              dashboardBody(
                h1("PROSENTASE MATERI TAHUN 2022"),
                
                actionButton(
                  inputId = "input1",
                  label = 'JAN'),                           
                actionButton(
                  inputId = 'input2',
                  label = 'FEB'),
                actionButton(
                  inputId = 'input3',
                  label = 'MAR'),
                actionButton(
                  inputId = 'input4',
                  label = 'APR'),
                actionButton(
                  inputId = 'input5',
                  label = 'MAY'),
                actionButton(
                  inputId = 'input6',
                  label = 'JUN'),
                actionButton(
                  inputId = 'input7',
                  label = 'JUL'),
                actionButton(
                  inputId = 'input8',
                  label = 'AUG'),
                actionButton(
                  inputId = 'input9',
                  label = 'SEP'),
                actionButton(
                  inputId = 'input10',
                  label = 'OCT'),
                actionButton(
                  inputId = 'input11',
                  label = 'NOV'),
                actionButton(
                  inputId = 'input12',
                  label = 'DES'),
              
                fluidPage(
                  plotOutput('inpoet')
                )
              )
)
```

And here's my server.R code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(readxl)
library(shinyalert)

# Data1 <- read_excel("Data1.xlsx")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$input1, {
      output$inpoet1 <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot1')
      })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$input2, {
      output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot2')
      })
    })
    observeEvent(input$input3, {
      output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot3')
      })
    })
    observeEvent(input$input4, {
      output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot4')
      })
    })
    observeEvent(input$input5, {
      output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot5')
      })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$input6, {
      output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot6')
      })
    })
    observeEvent(input$input7, {
      output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot7')
      })
    })
    observeEvent(input$input8, {
      output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot8')
      })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$input9, {
      output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot9')
      })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$input10, {
      output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot10')
      })
    })
    observeEvent(input$input11, {
      output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot11')
      })
    })
    observeEvent(input$input12, {
      output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
        plotOutput('plot12')
      })
    })
    
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("JAN"),
                       Percentage=c(90))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
    
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("FEB"),
                       Percentage=c(78))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
    
    output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("MAR"),
                       Percentage=c(100))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
    
    output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("APR"),
                       Percentage=c(99))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
    
    output$plot5 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("MAY"),
                       Percentage=c(90))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
    
    output$plot6 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("JUN"),
                       Percentage=c(78))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
    
    output$plot7 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("JUL"),
                       Percentage=c(100))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
    
    output$plot8 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("AUG"),
                       Percentage=c(87))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
    
    output$plot9 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("SEP"),
                       Percentage=c(90))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
    
    output$plot10 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("OCT"),
                       Percentage=c(78))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
    
    output$plot11 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("NOV"),
                       Percentage=c(100))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
    
    output$plot12 <- renderPlot({
      df <- data.frame(Month=c("DES"),
                       Percentage=c(100))
      head(df)
      p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        theme_minimal()
      p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
      p
      p + coord_flip()
    })
  }
  

  observeEvent(input$myButton, {
    shinyalert(title = "UPDL PANDAAN", imageUrl ="https://lms.pln-pusdiklat.co.id/assets/themes/rti/frontend/img/logo-pln.png", imageWidth = "50%", imageHeight = "50%") }
  )
```

I'm a beginner at this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it looks like you are trying to do relatively simple app (however it's OK to define complexity based on developer's experience I think).

I will show you how to make this simpler and how to make it works:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
library(shinyalert)

data1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     Month = c("JAN","FEB",
                               "MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP",
                               "OCT","NOV","DES"),
                     Percentage = c(90L,78L,100L,
                               99L,90L,78L,100L,87L,90L,78L,99L,100L)
        )

ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                                    dashboardHeader(title = "UPDL PANDAAN"),
                                    
                                    #sidebar
                                    dashboardSidebar(
                                      sidebarMenu(
                                        menuItem("WIG PMK 2020", tabName = "WIGPMK", icon = icon("tachometer-alt")),
                                        fluidPage(
                                          actionButton("myButton", "About Us")
                                        )
                                      )),
                                    dashboardBody(
                                      h1("PROSENTASE MATERI TAHUN 2022"),
                                      
                                      selectInput("month", "Choose month", choices = data1$Month),
                                        plotOutput('inpoet')
                                    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$inpoet <- renderPlot({
    df <- data1 %>% 
      filter(Month == input$month)
    p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, fill=Month)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      theme_minimal()
    p<-p + theme(legend.position="none")
    p
    p + coord_flip()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$myButton, {
    shinyalert(title = "UPDL PANDAAN", imageUrl ="https://lms.pln-pusdiklat.co.id/assets/themes/rti/frontend/img/logo-pln.png", imageWidth = "50%", imageHeight = "50%")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the app above I have removed `actionButton`s and used `selectInput`, so instead of buttons we will have a list. And in the `server` part I have left only one `renderPlot`. I have used one file (`app.R`, so on the bottom is `shinyApp(ui, server)` - this is needed if we have app in one file).

Let's take a closer look on all of this:

1. You need to remember that one `plotOutput` in `ui` part needs to be connected with one `renderPlot` in `server` part by the common `inputId`. So, because we have `plotOutput('inpoet')`, then we need to have `output$inpoet`. Without this you wouldn't see anything rendered on the screen.
2. How Shiny knows that - when new Month if chosen - it should display different plot? This is because of this code in `renderPlot`: `filter(Month == input$month)`. And the most important here is `input$month` - when you use `input$` in server part (and inside reactive context, so inside `reactive`, `eventReactive`, `observe`, `observeEvent` and any `render*` function), whenever this `input$` changes, then Shiny recomputes the new object (plot, data.frame or others) based on this new, changed value.

And let's take a closer look on your code:

1. This solution with `actionButton`s is bad, but I'm not sure how to explain it. Maybe look at my proposition - it is much less complex than yours. If you prefer to use something more similar to your app - check out the `radioButtons` from `shiny`.
2. You shouldn't nest reactives - this is a good practice to not nest them and it is just not necessary, probably in any scenario it won't be necessary.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reach out, i Tried your suggestions but this shows up :
Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    box


Attaching package: ‘shinyalert’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    runExample

Error in func(fname, ...) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.

Comment: and could you tell me why was the second value have "L" added to them

Comment: If you add "L" you will have integer, not double type. Try `typeof(1L)`, `typeof(1)`. It was added automatically, because I used `dput` fun to make `data.frame` - it doesn't change anything in real in our case. Regarding your first question - I would say the problem is that you do not open the app in a fresh session (try restart R, on windows it is ctrl + shift + F10 in RStudio), so some functions from packages are masked by different functions (but named the same!) from other packages. If you still will have a problem, ask another question and let me know (it is hard to make discussion here).